# Aplicação Tomcat + jsf + hibernate = Lento para inicializar

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, tomcat

A minha aplicação está com a inicialização muito lenta.

Segue o log do eclipse onde mais demora:

> INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory

Comment: @CesarMiguel você tem uma resposta? Essa única linha do log é mesmo suficiente para diagnosticar a causa da lentidão?

Comment: @bfavaretto, não tenho resposta, mas devia? Só editei a resposta

Comment: @CesarMiguel Achei que você teria editado com a intenção de prepará-la para uma reabertura.